# How to delete database without using any plugin?

Tags: database

I am using WordPress based web development. I am a beginner, somewhere on YouTube I learned that, to change domain name, install plugin "Better search and replace", and using it replaced my domain name with the desired domain name. But after that, the domain stopped responding. I replaced the whole WordPress file from the ftp server, but in the installation process, it shows the message, "Already Installed, You appear to have already installed WordPress. To reinstall please clear your old database tables first".
I have searched ways to do that, but everywhere it's saying to use plugins, which I can't do due to above mentioned issue.

Comment: Most web hosts provide access like phpMyAdmin. Check with your host and see what's available. You can either delete your database entirely or often restore a backup of your database from before you made the changes. It's always safer before doing major changes like domain replacement to back up the database manually, in case something like this happens. :)

Comment: Actually this domain is given by the instructor to me, for practice purpose. All I have is, Filezilla Confidentials and WordPress Database Confidentials and the domain name.

Comment: then go back with your Better seach and replace and reverse the changes?

Answer (score 1):

If the database server is available publicly you should be able to use a MySQL client to interact with it.

[Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) is a good one for mac, check [this list](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-MySQL-client-for-Mac-OS-X-or-Windows) if you need something for windows or linux.

If the database is only available locally on your web server, you might be able to upload a DB admin script like [adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) via filezilla and use that to interact with the database.

If all else fails you will likely have to go back to your instructor and ask him/her to reset the DB for you.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that doesn't require installing anything: clear the database with PHP. Possibly a little easier. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337158/how-can-i-use-php-to-delete-all-records-in-a-mysql-database/#answer-10337756), just replace host, username, password, and database_name with your own from `wp-config.php`. Save the file, upload it to your root folder, and access it in a web browser to run it.